# Is there an API for Frequent Location History on iOS?

Tags: ios, location

I noticed ["Frequent Locations"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7D1C.jpg) while rummaging through my settings on my iOS device.  I'm trying to build an app that basically combs through your location history, either by social network or by your device, and determines if you were at a particular event.  Does apple provide an API to access your recent frequent locations on your device?  I read through this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) but didn't see anything about location history.

Comment: did you ever get this answered? I'm curious too

Comment: Some updates on this?

Comment: @Matt Restivo any solution you found so far ?

Answer (score 0):

From reading the Apple API reference guide it looks like 'locationmanager(_:didVisit:)' would provide the information you're looking for. It would provide data on locations that the user was in for a extended period of time.

What Apple's definition of extended is, I'm not sure. But this should get anyone searching for the frequent locations data a bit closer than what was posted in response to this question.

In the 'Getting the Visited Locations' subsection of this link. 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager